# Un mismo ID tenga varios registros en SQL Server

Tags: sql

Tengo una duda acerca de como insertar varios registros pero que tenga el mismo ID en SQL Server, por ejemplo: Tengo una tabla de "Estado" pero cada estado tiene varios datos.

Mi tabla tiene las siguientes columnas: IdEstado(PK), NombreEstado y IdZona(FK)
Mi llave primaria la tengo como Identity(1,1)

El resultado que pretendo es el siguiente:

| IdEstado | Nombre | IdZona |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hidalgo | 2 |
| 1 | Hidalgo | 3 |

Les agradecería mucho si alguien me pudiese orientar para solucionar de la mejor manera este pequeño inconveniente.

Gracias :D

Comment: o sea, hay una columna extra que tiene tu llave primaria?

Comment: Lo que a mi se me ocurre es que crees un catalogo de estados, con un id para cada estado, luego en una tabla de detalles agregar el idEstado y ya los datos que quieras ingresar pero con un id de tabla detalles consecutivo

Comment: No es posible tener un `PK` con el mismo `ID`. Podrias indicarnos porque quieres hacer eso? Tal vez haya mejores soluciones

Comment: Lo que pretendo es visualizar los estados y las zonas que tiene.

Comment: @Mad96 cual es el tipo de relacion que tiene `estado-zona`. Uno a muchos? Muchos a muchos?

Comment: @JuanRivera Es de uno a muchos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como es una relacion de `uno-muchos / estado-zona`, deberias modificar tus tablas por lo siguiente:

1. Tabla `estado`: En un estado puede haber muchas zonas

| IdEstado | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hidalgo |

2. Tabla `zona`: En una zona, puede haber muchos estados

| IdZona | IdEstado |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

Comment: Te agradezco tu orientación proporcionada, tu respuesta me ayudo mucho, ya que desde hace un tiempo largo no eh ocupado SQL y hasta ahora estoy retomando tal herramienta. Nuevamente gracias.